# Assertion Error:C++ FAIL: Expected 1 Was 2

Tags: c++

My functions are failling and giving unexpected values. The defination: UNINITIALIZED 0, OKAY 1, ERROR 2.I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently facing some issues with the testing of our water flow sensor, and I'm seeking your assistance in troubleshooting the problem.
In the water_flow_read function, I'm encountering unexpected behavior when testing for valid flow rates in the range of 17 - 500 ml/s.The issue occurs in the water_flow_read function in the water_flow module. I expect that the code correctly identifies flow rates within the valid range and sets the status to "OKAYor ERROR."

```
uint8_t water_flow_read(uint16_t *flow_rate)

{ if (status != UNINITIALIZED)
    { status = ERROR;
       if (flow_rate != NULL)
        { // Calculate the flow rate according to the number of pulses
            *flow_rate = WATER_FLOW_MAX_PER_SEC * pulse_counter/ cab_factor;
            // Check for errors if everything is fine then
          if ((*flow_rate >= WATER_FLOW_MIN_PER_SEC) && (*flow_rate <= WATER_FLOW_MAX_PER_SEC))
            {
                status = OKAY;
            }

            bsp_interrupt_disable();
            pulse_counter = 0;
            bsp_interrupt_enable();
           }
       }
         return status
      }
```

The test code is not correctly identifying flow rates within the valid range, and the status remains "ERROR."`I've tested the function with various inputs and verified that the problem persists.

```
void test_water_flow_read(void)
{

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(ERROR, water_flow_read(NULL));

    uint16_t value = 0;
    bsp_set_digital_value(100);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(WATER_FLOW_SENSOR_PIN, bsp_get_pin_num());
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(OKAY, water_flow_read(&value));
    

    bsp_set_digital_value(600);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(ERROR, water_flow_read(&value));
}
```

Comment: If, at the beginning of the function, `status == UNINITIALIZED`, then the function doesn't do anything and returns `status` unchanged.

Comment: The test has `uint16_t value = 0;`, then does a couple of function calls that, as far as I can tell, can't possibly change `value`, and then passes `&value` to `water_flow_read`. So within `water_flow_read`, `*flow_rate` is still zero. What is `bsp_set_digital_value`, what exactly does it set?

Comment: Well, show the code that works alongside the code that doesn't, if you hope for someone to spot the difference. Better still, prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Hi! I have three other sensors i  i have implimented almost the same and the tests are working fine for example soil moisture sensor its working as it should be. bsp_set_dogital_value is a helper function in the mock of bsp. It returns digital_value and digital value is equal to value which is declared to 0. More like this void bsp_set_digital_value(int value)
{
    digital_value = value;
}

Comment: So `bsp_set_digital_value` updates a variable named `digital_value`. But that's not the variable you pass to `water_flow_read`. The variable you do pass to `water_flow_read`, named `value`, still has the value zero.

Comment: My file structure is like this lib/bsp/bsp.cpp/bsp.h then lib/water_flow/water_flow.cpp/water_flow.h. src/main.cpp. test/test_water/bsp.cpp/bsp.h/test.cpp . So in water_flow iam only using functions in lib/bsp then in test.cpp im using functions in test_water_flow plus lib/bsp header file. So the bsp in test is only for testing purposes.

Comment: {

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(ERROR, soil_moisture_read(NULL));

    uint8_t value = 0;
    bsp_set_analog_value(500);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(OKAY, soil_moisture_read(&value));
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(SOIL_MOISTURE_PIN, bsp_get_pin_num());
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(48, value);

    bsp_set_analog_value(1024);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(ERROR, soil_moisture_read(&value));

    bsp_set_analog_value(0);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(ERROR, soil_moisture_read(&value));
}
This works without any problems

Comment: Since you are using C++, you ought to compare the flow_rate with nullptr instead of NULL. It does not solve the problem, but it is a better practice.

Comment: Oh ok. Will do that. Thanks

Comment: BTW: Formatting code consistently makes it easier to read and to spot problems. Also, quite frankly, you deter people from reading your code here if you don't.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?